# ImportError: cannot import name DropoutEmbedding

Tags: keras

Following code gives me an import error.

```
from keras.layers.embeddings import DropoutEmbedding
```

What did DropoutEmbedding change its name to? Or what substitute should I use?

Comment: `Dropout,Embedding`? they are two kinds of layers in Keras.

Comment: What I think you are searching for is just called `Embedding`. It is the only Layer inside `keras.layers.embeddings`. Please elaborate a bit more what you want to do with this layer.

Comment: You are probably using some custom code or keras version that has a class called DropoutEmbedding, but this is not part of any official Keras version. I have seen some code from Yarin Gal that mentions DropoutEmbedding

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes it's Yarin's RNN code. I found that 0.2.0 has DropoutEmbedding but it's a very old version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "DropoutEmbedding" layer in Keras. I think you are looking for "Dropout" and "Embedding" layers. Import them like this:

```py
from keras.layers import Dropout,Embedding
```